# Kivy button class not executing follow up commands

Tags: python, button, kivy, behavior

i've been trying to work out a way to make an easy dictionary iterator with some filters alongside the way in order to be able to access to each specific subdirectory containing the links to the database.
I've already tried to do each button separately but it didn't work... prolly mostly because i'm a little bit new to this environment.

class Filtros(App):

```
def build(self):
    root_widget = BoxLayout(orientation ='vertical')
    button_symbols= (
      "Precio",
      'Ubicacion',
      "Informacion de Envio",
      "Sabores",
      "Dieta Especial",
      "Fotos",
      "Reviews",
      "Puntos",
      "Tiempo de Preparacion",
      "Porciones",
      "Nombre",
      "Adicionales",)
    button_grid = GridLayout(cols= 4, size_hint_y= 6)
    for symbol in button_symbols:             
         button_grid.add_widget(Button(text = symbol))   
    root_widget.add_widget(button_grid)
    return root_widget
```

class MyButton(ButtonBehavior, App):

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
     super(MyButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)    
def on_state(self, widget, value):
     if value == 'down':
        prec_lay = GridLayout(cols= 2, size_hint_y=5)
        prec_net = "Precio Neto"                
        prec_tot = "Precio Total"                
        prec_lay.add_widget(Button(text= prec_org))
        return prec_lay
```

Comment: be specific about what your problem is

Comment: Thanks for the anaswer. Currently the button function once clicked, doesn't display the second part of the code.